# Regex command is replacing two characters instead of one

Tags: regex, perl, whitespace, substitution

I am attempting to replace the spaces in my string with an under-bar. With my limited coding experience, I have come up with this -

```
s/\b[ ]\D/_/g
```

This command works in finding all of the appropriate selections of my file however, it replaces the space and the proceeding character rather than only the space. How can I insure it only replaces the whitespaces and no additional characters?
Also, I would not like this to affect number characters (hence the \D).

Comment: How do you mean "not affect number characters"? Spaces are not numbers, so replacing spaces with underscores by definition doesn't affect numbers. But I'm guessing you are trying to say something a little more complex.

Answer (score 1):

The regex `\b[ ]\D` (which could also be written as `\b \D`, by the way) matches the space and the following non-digit character, so that's what's replaced with an underscore.

There are two (well, there are more, but these two are the straightforward ones) ways go go about fixing this in Perl:

**With a capture group and back reference:**

```
s/\b (\D)/_\1/g
```

Here the regex will still match the space and the non-digit character, but the non-digit character will be remembered as `\1` and used as part of the replacement.

**With a lookahead zero-length assertion:**

```
s/\b (?=\D)/_/g
```

`(?=\D)` matches the empty string if (and only if) it is followed by something matching `\D`, so the non-digit character is no longer part of the match and is not replaced.

**Addendum:** By the way, I suspect you meant to use `\b\D` instead of just `\D`. `\D` matches spaces (because they are not digits), therefore

```
$ echo 'foo 123 bar  baz qux' | perl -pe 's/\b (?=\D)/_/g'
foo 123_bar_ baz_qux
```

as opposed to

```
$ echo 'foo 123 bar  baz qux' | perl -pe 's/\b (?=\b\D)/_/g'
foo 123_bar  baz_qux
```

Comment: Keep in mind that `[ ]` is more visible than ` ` and should you decide to improve the formatting of your pattern by using `/x`, it still works.

Answer (score -2):

Try 
   s/\s/_/g

The \s is the character that will match all whitespace.
If you are worried about abutting spaces use \s+ 
the + means 1 or more whitespace characters.